# Keep numerator inline with rest of equation

Tags: amsmath, fractions

In the following example, I would like to to keep the `Q''(p)` on the same line as the rest of the equation, and put the vinculum and `2` underneath.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:3of3}
  \int_{0}^{1} \phi(p)\frac{Q''(p)}{2} \int_{0}^{1} (\Delta p)^{2}\mathcal{P}(\Delta p)\; \mathrm{d}p'\; \mathrm{d}p
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The equation currently looks like this:
[image]

And I would like something like this:
[image]

Comment: Why not put `\phi(p)` in the numerator, as well?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What would be the special meaning?

Comment: @Andrew Oh, I could, and honestly, I'm not sure I like either of these layouts.  Most likely I will just use `\frac{1}{2}` in front of the  `Q''`.  I was just curious how one could do this.

Comment: @egreg, Thanks! I am not sure of any special meaning, just curious as to how one could do this.  Maybe not for this eq. but perhaps somewhere down the road this would be useful.

Comment: @AGS Yes, it can be done, of course. But it's contrary to centuries of mathematical typography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "crazy" variant of a fraction is generated by `\underline` and an operator subscript:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:3of3}
  \int_{0}^{1} \phi(p)\mathop{\underline{Q''(p)}}\limits_{\textstyle2}
  \int_{0}^{1} (\Delta p)^{2}\mathcal{P}(\Delta p)\; \mathrm{d}p'\; \mathrm{d}p
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

For comparison, other variants from the comments:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:3of3}
  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\phi(p)\, Q''(p)}{2}
  \int_{0}^{1} (\Delta p)^{2}\mathcal{P}(\Delta p)\; \mathrm{d}p'\; \mathrm{d}p
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:3of3}
  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2}\,\phi(p)\, Q''(p)
  \int_{0}^{1} (\Delta p)^{2}\mathcal{P}(\Delta p)\; \mathrm{d}p'\; \mathrm{d}p
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With smaller digits:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:3of3}
  \int_{0}^{1} \tfrac{1}{2}\, \phi(p)\, Q''(p)
  \int_{0}^{1} (\Delta p)^{2}\mathcal{P}(\Delta p)\; \mathrm{d}p'\; \mathrm{d}p
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 13):

With no measurement (available only in display math mode):

```
\def\crazyfrac#1#2{\raisebox{-\fontdimen8\textfont2}{$\displaystyle\frac{#1}{#2}$}}
```

[image]

It's horrible and, above all, confusing. I decline any responsibility in case of use of this macro in a real document.

Comment: +1 we should get this engraved on your tombstone (not that you need one yet)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Inside a 257 side regular polygon constructed with ruler and compass in TikZ.

Answer (score 8):

Don't do this or @egreg will never forgive me.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\horriblefrac#1#2{%
  \setbox0\hbox{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{$\displaystyle\frac{#1}{#2}$}
  \dimen0\ht0
  \advance\dimen0-\ht2
  \raise \dimen0 \box2}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:3of3}
  \int_{0}^{1} \phi(p)\horriblefrac{Q''(p)}{2} \int_{0}^{1} (\Delta p)^{2}\mathcal{P}(\Delta p)\; \mathrm{d}p'\; \mathrm{d}p
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're forgiven, but my macro is better than yours.